# bitbucket API 2.0 page parameters using non-default pagelen

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I have run into a cumbersome limitation of the bitbucket API 2.0 - I am hoping there is a way to make it more usable.

When one wants to retrieve a list of repositories from the bitbucket API 2.0, this url can be used:

```
https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{teamname}
```

This returns the first 10 repos in the list.  To access the next 10, one simply needs to add a page parameter:

```
https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{teamname}?page=2
```

This returns the next 10.  One can also adjust the number of results returned using the pagelen parameter, like so:

```
https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{teamname}?pagelen=100
```

The maximum number can vary per account, but 100 is the maximum any team is able to request with each API call.  The cumbersome part is that I cannot find a way to get page 2 with a pagelen of 100. I have tried variations on the following:

```
https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{teamname}?pagelen=100&page=2
https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{teamname}?page=2&pagelen=100
```

I've also tried using parameters such as `limit` or `size` to no avail.  Is the behavior I seek even possible? [Some relevant documentation can be found here.](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** It appears this behavior is possible, however the bitbucket 2.0 API will only recognize multiple parameters if the entire url is in quotes.

Example:

`curl "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{teamname}?pagelen=100&page=2"`

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**  I was able to get around this by creating a bash script that looped through each page of 10 results, adding each new 10 repos to a temporary file and then cloning into those 10 repos. The only manual thing that needs to be done is to update the upper limit in the for loop to be the last page expected.

Here is an example script:

```
for thisPage in {1..23}
    do
        curl https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/[organization]?page=$thisPage -u [username]:[password] > repoinfo

        for repo_name in `cat repoinfo | sed -r 's/("slug": )/\n\1/g' | sed -r 's/"slug": "(.*)"/\1/' | sed -e 's/{//' | cut -f1 -d\" | tr '\n' ' '`
            do
                echo "Cloning " $repo_name
                git clone https://[username]@bitbucket.org/[organization]/$repo_name
                echo "---"
            done
    done
```

Much help was gleaned from:
https://haroldsoh.com/2011/10/07/clone-all-repos-from-a-bitbucket-source/
and http://adomingues.github.io/2015/01/10/clone-all-repositories-from-a-user-bitbucket/ Thanks!